# Statistic for pages and number of symbols

Tags: logic

I should complete the following table (put number, where ? sign stands):

Pages____Symbols
107______?
281______735
555______1557

Well obvious variant was to find weight:
1557/555 = 2.805 symbols per page
735/281 = 2.616 symbols per page

Seems like it's not geometric nor arithmetic progression...

I'm stuck... Please give a hint on solution.

Comment: I would just use $2.7$ symbols per page and call it good.  You don't have enough information to do anything else.  You could argue that the $555$ is twice as big a sample so you should weight it twice as much.

Comment: Well, somehow I should get integer number. Maybe I should look at their ratio as a sequence ?/107, 735/281, 1557/555. I   tried several numbers through wolfram alpha to check if it s the sequence, but it isn't...

Comment: Just round off whatever you get to an integer.  We are just doing an estimate, so anything reasonable is a good answer.

Comment: That's why I add this question here, there is a certain solution for this... That question was on job interview...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a trick question, not a statistics or mathematics question.  The answer is 213.  It takes 213 digits to write the numbers 1 to 107 in decimal notation.  As seen by this output in a shell window:

```
seq 281|tr -dc 0-9 |wc
   0       1     735
seq 555|tr -dc 0-9 |wc
   0       1    1557
seq 107 | tr -dc 0-9 |wc
   0       1     213
```

Comment: just wow... how did you manage to figure out that?

Comment: I don't know.  It just popped in my head, as something to try.